# How to add Price per sqft in Product page and exact price in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, price, catalog-price-rules

[image: In catagory Page price is in Sqft and in Product page it is in Per piece.]

How to add the price in per sqft in Catagory Page and search page? On the product page, the actual price will be shown as per the size chosen in the drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

Magento doesn't actually has specific unit of measurement, I mean to say, you can consider the price for any unit you want i.e either $95 per KG or $95 per sq. ft. It's only how you think of it is. If you consider the price for sq.ft and it will be so.

So for your problem above.

In the product detail page, i can see that the price is Rs.3540 so what you have to do is add the product price to 3540. and for the option and additional price, you can manage that from custom option.

If you open the product on the right hand side you will see a tab named "**Custom Options**" you can add the options from there. Actually it is easy to add custom option see [this](https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-add-custom-options-in-magento-2/)  for detail info.

Hope this helps. If it does, don't forget to accept and vote up.

Cheers!!

Comment: Not working as per your guide. I need to show the price per sqft in the category page.

Comment: The price in the product listing will be the price that you added from the admin on product price, if you want the text per sqft, you can add it on template "catalog/product/list.phtml"

Comment: Then it will be added to all the products.. Isnt it. I need it for specific products only.

Comment: If that is the case then create an attribute with dropdown type. Add option of per sq and other if you need. On frontend check the attribute value and if it is set to per square then add it else not. You can create yes/No type attribute too , if that suits your requirement

Comment: I would like to implement it. Can you guide me for that?